# How do I switch the certificate from development to production?

Tags: ios, ssl, parse-platform, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to testflight my app, but when I use notifications I get an error because I have a development APN instead of a production APN. My problem is uploading it to parse. First I created a development SSL Certificate, then I went back and did a Production SSL Certificate, but I am having trouble uploading the Production Certificate because It's not an APN, rather a Apple Push Services. I also created a Distribution Provisioning (ad hoc).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apples Push Notification service is a bit strange:

**On the client side:**
If you build your client with Xcode you usually build a "Debug" version of your app. In that case the registerForRemoteNotification method will create a sandbox device token for you.

If you build a "Release" version of your app the same method create a production device token for you.

**On the server side:**
If you have a sandbox device token you can only send a push notification to that device if you use Apples sandbox Push Notification service with your sandbox SSL certificate.

If you have a production device token then you have to use Apples production push notification service with your production SSL certificate to send a push notification to that device.

**The tricky part is:**

1. if you only have a device token you will not know if it is a production  device token or a sandbox device token.
2. if you want to use release and debug clients against the same server, that server has to use the sandbox and the production service at the same time. And you need a mechanism to decide when to use which service.

BTW: there is a nice tutorial by Ray Wenderlich which also contains a useful PHP script for easy testing.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: I'm still very lost, sorry I'm very new to this. So I need to upload a certificate to parse, and they only accept APNs and I need a Production APNs Certificate. I'm following multiple instructions but instead I get Apple Push Services.

Comment: Ah, I see ... "upload to parse" as in https://parse.com/ the web service. Sorry, I never used Parse. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.... :-/

Comment: Yeah, but that's fine parse is not much of a problem, the problem is creating a production certificate. In the image above it says Apple Push Services, and the development one it says APNs Development, I need that for the production so instead of Apple Push Services it is APNs Production.

Comment: It seems there is a issue on Apples side of things https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28701